# Reading Excel with C# and column type problems

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am having nightmare problems reading Excel files with `C#/OleDb`. I am up against the well-known problem of something deciding that a column is numeric when it is not.

The first `15` rows are `numeric`, but later cells in that column are not, and are thus read as `null`! This is insane. I know about `IMEX` etc but there is always some final `gotcha`, usually

> "could not find installable IASM" or something about Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.

The fixes to these problems are not trivial and seem to be full of traps.

I really want nothing to do with Jet etc etc and all the maintenance/installer issues that it involves, never mind hassles when installing the app on a client machine.

Is there any way that I can simply read an Excel sheet into a DataTable with me deciding what types are involved and which does not have a dependency on MS Access (!?) or any of these Office-ey files at all and, above all, does not make its own unilateral decisions about what types to use and whether to import one cell value and not another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the OpenXML SDK, its great.

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-and-Import-Excel-data-to-DataTable-using-OpenXml-in-ASPNet-with-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Fantastic. Got that working in minutes. I had struggled with NPOI to no avail (wouldn't build, then was outdated wrt file format...) and it seems very messy compared with this.

Comment: please mark the answer as correct or useful if you found it helpful!

Comment: Was holding out for more replies, but your suggestion is working well. Thanks.